# Group documents by day and keep empty groups in MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want find how many documents were created each day in the last 90 days. However, I also want to include empty matches, so if there are no documents matching the query, document would still be included in the results with the count of 0.

This is a part of my aggregation pipeline, grouping documents by day:

```
[{
    $match: {
        createdAt: {
            $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                date: "$createdAt"
            }
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        date: "$_id",
        count: 1,
    }
}]
```

Example results are:

```
[{
    count: 1,
    date: "2023-03-10"
}, {
    count: 5,
    date: "2023-03-07"
}]
```

However, I want to include all groups if 90 days, event if there are no matches. For example:

```
[{
    count: 0,
    date: "2023-03-11"
}, {
    count: 2,
    date: "2023-03-12"
}, {
    count: 0,
    date: "2023-03-13"
}, /* All 90 days */ ]
```

I tried using `$bucket` and `$bucketAuto` operators but these, despite the name, does not appear to be suitable for achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate last 90 days offset array using `$range` first. Then use `$map` with `$dateAdd` to get the last 90 dates. Perform a self `$lookup` with date-only comparison to get the records belongs to the date.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      offset: {
        "$range": [
          -90,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      date: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$offset",
          "as": "o",
          "in": {
            $dateTrunc: {
              date: {
                "$dateAdd": {
                  "startDate": "$$NOW",
                  "unit": "day",
                  "amount": "$$o"
                }
              },
              unit: "day"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$date"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        "dt": "$date"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  "$dateTrunc": {
                    date: "$key",
                    unit: "day"
                  }
                },
                "$$dt"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$count": "cnt"
        }
      ],
      "as": "records"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: 1,
      count: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $first: "$records.cnt"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pNZT6Z8U-KR)